# No padding for UITableView by default

Tags: uitableview, padding

I created a UITableView and added a static content.
When I run the app, there is no padding at the top.

[image: Image showing no padding for the app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put your table view inside a UIViewController (and not a UITableViewController), you can add as much padding as you want at the top (or bottom, or sides) of your content view.

Comment: I know, but what if I want to use UITableViewController ?

Comment: I don't think there are that many (if any) benefits to using a UITableViewController versus a UIViewController. [In Apple's documentation for UITableViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), I see three extra properties in addition to the init method.

Comment: Can you refresh a TableView that is placed in UIViewController in a way that you can do in a UITableViewController ?

Comment: sure... that's what the "`reloadData`" method of a UITableView is for.